# Creating a Football Betting System [PHP & WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, system

If I were to create a small online football betting "system", where the user would be able to put two numbers in each textbox, which represented the goalscorings by the selected teams (i.e. Arsenal 3 - 0 Chelsea). And then, depending on the real-life result, the user should be rewarded with a currency (only on the website - not in real-life), 100P for a correct bet, 50P for almost and finally 0 for totally wrong - just to give an example.

How would I go about creating that? I'm guessing I'd be using a rather simple PHP for it? I'm running the project on the CMS WordPress, so user-integration, databases to store the currency, etc.. are already available, amongst other very useful features for the system, I presume. I'd probably enter the real-life, correct values manually into my website, to ease the programming pain, but it'd need an automatic feature for it to deliver the Points to the corresponding user-account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create betting form in html
2. submit user's bet to a SQL database table "bats" attached to their username and the gameid of a particular game
3. have another table "scores" with the actual score for that game attached to the gameid
4. when the user logs in / views their bets page if the score is in the "scores" table (rather than the row being null / whatever default value) it will then issue them a score
5. simple PHP can determine how far off they were

Theres the breakdown, go use google

Comment: I've been googling and googling - even for WordPress plug-ins, as well for modules for Drupal. No results. What am I by the way doing wrong regarding the post I made? It received a few thumbs down?

Comment: Your question is waayy to vague and you need to go and do some research of your own, and only come here is you have a specific coding issue, not asking the internet community to plan out your project for you. I recieved '-1's' too. lol.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask you for a follow-up? Thanks in advance! I'm creating a .sql file for the tables - 'bets' and 'scores' - and I'm trying to figure out, which names and what content the columns should contain. In 'bets', I've figured out that 'ID' and 'user_login' (from WordPress) should be used to specify the correct user, and for his bets, there should be two columns: home_team and away_team, which contains his goalscoring prediction. But that wouldn't work, since there is more than 1 set of goalscorings, which needs to be specified at a time. What would you do, techjunkie? Thank you so much!

Comment: 1. Don't worry about .sql files, you have no need; go use this software: http://www.heidisql.com/download.php.
2. Every table needs a auto_increment, not_null primary key.
3. I'd have the "Scores" table set up with id(primary), hometeam, awayteam, dateofgame, homescore, awayscore.
4. I'd have the "Bets" table with id(primary), gameid(corresponding to id from 'Scores', username/email/whatever, homebet, awaybet
5. Each row in the "Bet" table would be a new bet (each user can have multiple rows)

Comment: Okay, let me get this straight:

User (inputs "home_bet" & "away_bet" on website) -> User receives "gameid" -> a row gets created in table "bets", containing: ID (user ID), gameid (assigned auto.) and home_ and away_bet. 

But how does the data from "bets"-table get to the "scores"-table, and the "scores"-table is just containing the real-life results, which I input, when the games over, right?

"Scores"-tabel have a "scoreid", which corresponds to bets' "gameid". Home_ and away_team (all teams have ids as well in separate table(?)), and home_ & away_score (the real-life results(?)). 

Thanks!

Comment: No feedback on my question, techjunkie.css? It's okay; just making sure, since it's quite fatal for the development of the system.

Comment: Mostly that's right, you sound like you're getting confused though. the gameid column for the bets table would correspond to the auto-increment id key of the games table. When a user goes to bet on a game, they have to be able to find their game by location, or home/away team. Every row in the games table should have 'id', 'location', 'home', 'away', 'homescore', 'awayscore'. this way it can be set up for people to find a game easily.

Comment: Now as long as the 'homescore' and 'awayscore' fields are null (or some default value, like 'unset') for a particular game, betting is open. when someone bets, I'd suggest in the bets table having 'id'(key), 'gameid'(this is input upon betting), 'userid'(corresponding to a user id in a "Users" table - also necessary, 'homebet', 'awaybet'. When you add the scores to the games table you need a script to recognize that those values aren't null anymore, calculate the winner, and then calculate each users winnings.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I presume that a valid way of completing this task, would to do like this link suggest: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Finally, how do I then connect two tables' rows together? Like when we want the 'userid' in the 'bets'-table to correspond to the user id in a 'Users'-table? How'd you go around completing that?

Comment: each row in the users table would be 1 user - the the auto-inc primary key field define their id automatically, then when they bet, put that in the userid field in the bets table via the insert query. You can pull and define their userid from the users table in a session variable when they log in.

Comment: I have all the information I need now to do it! Thank you so much, Techjunkie! Just to make sure - this is going to be the final question, ever; as the link shows: w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp that's how I should do it, right? Once again, thanks!

Comment: for adding new users and bets, or adding any new rows. To update existing rows, use the UPDATE clause, use DELETE for deletions obviously, and thats it.